# Onclick cannot find function to execute

Tags: javascript

I am using an onclick() function to add an item to cart.

```
<button class='btn pull-right' id = 'cartBtn' onclick = 'addToCart(<?php echo $id;?>)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></button>
```

This is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cart = [];
    var id = $("#itemId").text();
    var stockAvailable = $("itemStock").text();
    var inCart = false;


    function addToCart(item){
        id = item;
            if (inCart == true){
                console.log("item already in cart");
            }
            else{
                cart.push(id);

            }

    }
```

However, I get the following error in the console upon clicking the button:

```
ReferenceError: addToCart is not defined
```

I have written the js code on a separate file and inluded it in the head section. 
What could be the problem here

Comment: Just write function outside "$(document).ready" because function doesn't need to wait until jquery gets initialised.

Comment: this is exactly your script is?

Comment: Yeah, thats the script

Comment: aren't you getting more syntax error or something?

Comment: @RAVIPATEL no. The only problem is that the onclick() function cannot seem to find the addToCart() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the official jquery docs. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

TLDR: `document.ready` runs only once so define your function outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use addToCart without defining it.
You can define it in the place where you want to use this function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function addToCart(item) {
    console.log('added');
  }
});
addToCart('item');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Right way

```js
function addToCart(item) {
  console.log('added');
}
$(document).ready(function() {

});
addToCart('item');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have defined it in an external script.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am showing you very basic example code based on your question

```js
var id, cart = [], stockAvailable, inCart = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
  id = $("#itemId").text();
  stockAvailable = $("itemStock").text();
});

function addToCart(item){
  id = item;
  if (inCart == true){
      console.log("item already in cart");
  }
  else{
      cart.push(id);
      inCart = true;
      console.log("item added in cart");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn pull-right' id = 'cartBtn' onclick = 'addToCart(1)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways you are using Jquery, so can you please check with jquery event handler.

Please find the answer using jquery click event.

```
$("#cartBtn").on("click", function(item){
       id = item;
            if (inCart == true){
                console.log("item already in cart");
            }
            else{
                cart.push(id);

            }
        }
   })
```